# SQL convert varchar 2/3 to 0.6 ( fraction to decimal)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have string saved in column 
23.42/3 .............
I have to extract 2/3 and convert it as 0.6
Extracting is not a problem  converting varchar value  2/3  to 0.6 is a issue.
2/3 is not fixed number,it can be any fraction I have to convert it to decimal

Comment: You are trying to do something that should not be done, for several reasons. First, if one of your queries need to separate 2 from 3, these data should be stored in different fields (first normal form). Second, you are storing a number as a string. I think that the correct question is: "How should this table be re-designed"?

Comment: How do you know that it's only the "2" before the slash that needs to be extracted? What if the string value is **`23.411/16`**...  do you read that as `1/16` or do you read that as `11/16`?

Comment: spencer7593  I will read it as 1/1

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, assuming that there is only one slash character in the string value, you can use an expression like the one aliased as `res` in this query:

```
SELECT t.str
     , RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.str,'/',1),1)+0 AS num
     , LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.str,'/',-1),1)+0 AS den

     , (RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.str,'/',1),1)+0)
         /  (LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.str,'/',-1),1)+0) AS res

  FROM ( SELECT '1234.62/4' AS str
         UNION ALL SELECT '1/4'
         UNION ALL SELECT '11/16'
         UNION ALL SELECT '/5'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'foo/5'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'fee3/4fi5/6'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'bar/'
         UNION ALL SELECT '/'
         UNION ALL SELECT ''
       ) t
```

returns:

```
  str             num     den       res  
  -----------  ------  ------  --------
  1234.62/4         2       4       0.5
  1/4               1       4      0.25
  11/16             1       1         1
  /5                0       5         0
  foo/5             0       5         0
  fee3/4fi5/6       3       6       0.5
  bar/              0       0    (NULL)
  /                 0       0    (NULL)
                    0       0    (NULL)
```

The expression for `res` is just the expression for `num` (numerator) divided by the expression for `den` (denominator). Those extra columns are returned as a demonstration of how those work. Doing the division is simple.

If you need to verify that there is at most one slash, before you evaluate the expression to calculate the decimal value from the fraction, you could use an expression like this...

```
  SELECT IF(CHAR_LENGTH(t.str)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.str,'/',''))=1, expr, 0)
```

just replace `expr` in that with the expression you use for `res` in the query above.